# Сортировка в колонках таблицы

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Как сделать сортировку как тут: [Плагин jQuery для сортировки HTML-таблиц](http://w3pro.ru/article/plagin-jquery-dlya-sortirovki-html-tablits)?

Дело в том, что этот способ не работает, так как у меня данные не готовые (не написаны), а выводятся из `MySQL`

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php');

//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `applications` ORDER BY `id`") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT `devices`.*, `selects`.deviceName AS name_device, `divisions`.divisionName AS divisionName
    FROM `devices`

    LEFT JOIN `selects`
    ON `selects`.id = `devices`.name_device

    LEFT JOIN `divisions`
    ON `divisions`.id = `devices`.division

    ORDER BY `devices`.id") or die(mysql_error());

$text = '
<table border="1" style="width:100%;" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <!--th style="text-align:center;" width="1%">№</th-->
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="1%;" vertical-align="middle";>Наименование</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="8%">Сетевое имя</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="6%">IP</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="3%">Кабинет</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="3%">Отдел</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="18%">Спецификация</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="5%">Пользователи</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="9%">Серийный номер</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="8%">Инвентарный номер</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" width="1%"><input type="checkbox" id="selall" value="1" class="checkbox"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$text .= '
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <!--td>'.$row['id'].'</td-->
                <td>'.$row['name_device'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['netname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['ip'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['room'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['divisionName'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['cp'].", ".$row['motherboard'].", ".$row['ram'].", ".$row['hdd'].", ".$row['vga'].", ".$row['dvd'].", ".$row['corpus'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['users'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['serial_number'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['invent_number'].'</td>
                <td><input  type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="" name="ip[]"></td>
            </tr>
</tbody>';

}
$text .= '';
$text = str_replace('1900-01-01','<span style="color:blue">Не выдан</span>',$text);
echo $text;

   //Закрываем соединение
   @mysql_close($result);
?>
```

Comment: Религия не позволяет сделать выборку из MySQL, которую далее обернуть в html код как в примере?

Comment: А я всё написал, что неясно? Как сделать выборку из MySQL или обернуть её в html код?

Comment: У меня и так есть выборка всех полей и данных из MySQL и оборачивается в HTML

Comment: код в студию

Comment: Добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `head` вставить `jquery-latest.js` и `jquery.tablesorter.js`, для таблицы добавить `id`, например, `<table border="1" style="width:100%;" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">` тег `<tbody>` и `</tbody>` нужно убрать из цикла `while`.
И добавить в `echo "<tbody>$text</tbody>";` и всё заработает.